# Strange IOCP behaviour when communicating with browsers

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, winsock, iocp

I'm writing IOCP server for video streaming from desktop client to browser.
Both sides uses WebSocket protocol to unify server's achitecture (and because there is no other way for browsers to perform a full-duplex exchange).

The working thread starts like this:

```
unsigned int __stdcall WorkerThread(void * param){
    int ThreadId = (int)param;
    OVERLAPPED *overlapped = nullptr;
    IO_Context *ctx = nullptr;
    Client *client = nullptr;
    DWORD transfered = 0;
    BOOL QCS = 0;

    while(WAIT_OBJECT_0 != WaitForSingleObject(EventShutdown, 0)){
        QCS = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(hIOCP, &transfered, (PULONG_PTR)&client, &overlapped, INFINITE);

        if(!client){
            if( Debug ) printf("No client\n");
            break;
        }
        ctx = (IO_Context *)overlapped;
        if(!QCS || (QCS && !transfered)){
            printf("Error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            DeleteClient(client);
            continue;
        }

        switch(auto opcode = client->ProcessCurrentEvent(ctx, transfered)){
            // Client owed to receive some data
            case OPCODE_RECV_DEBT:{ 
                if((SOCKET_ERROR == client->Recv()) && (WSA_IO_PENDING != WSAGetLastError())) DeleteClient(client);
                break;
            }
            // Client received all data or the beginning of new message
            case OPCODE_RECV_DONE:{ 
                std::string message;
                client->GetInput(message);
                // Analizing the first byte of WebSocket frame
                switch( opcode = message[0] & 0xFF ){ 
                    // HTTP_HANDSHAKE is 'G' - from GET HTTP...
                    case HTTP_HANDSHAKE:{
                        message = websocket::handshake(message);
                        while(!client->SetSend(message)) Sleep(1); // Set outgoing data
                        if((SOCKET_ERROR == client->Send()) && (WSA_IO_PENDING != WSAGetLastError())) DeleteClient(client);
                        break;
                    }
                    // Browser sent a closing frame (0x88) - performing clean WebSocket closure
                    case FIN_CLOSE:{
                        websocket::frame frame;
                        frame.parse(message);
                        frame.masked = false;
                        if( frame.pl_len == 0 ){
                            unsigned short reason = 1000;
                            frame.payload.resize(sizeof(reason));
                            frame.payload[0] = (reason >> 8) & 0xFF;
                            frame.payload[1] =  reason       & 0xFF;
                        }
                        frame.pack(message);
                        while(!client->SetSend(message)) Sleep(1);
                        if((SOCKET_ERROR == client->Send()) && (WSA_IO_PENDING != WSAGetLastError())) DeleteClient(client);
                        shutdown(client->Socket(), SD_SEND);
                        break;
                    }
```

IO context struct:

```
struct IO_Context{
    OVERLAPPED overlapped;
    WSABUF data;
    char buffer[IO_BUFFER_LENGTH];
    unsigned char opcode;
    unsigned long long debt;
    std::string message;
    IO_Context(){
        debt = 0;
        opcode = 0;
        data.buf = buffer;
        data.len = IO_BUFFER_LENGTH;
        overlapped.Offset = overlapped.OffsetHigh = 0;
        overlapped.Internal = overlapped.InternalHigh = 0;
        overlapped.Pointer = nullptr;
        overlapped.hEvent = nullptr;
    }
    ~IO_Context(){ while(!HasOverlappedIoCompleted(&overlapped)) Sleep(1); }
};
```

Client Send function:

```
int Client::Send(){
    int var_buf = O.message.size();
    // "O" is IO_Context for Output
    O.data.len = (var_buf>IO_BUFFER_LENGTH)?IO_BUFFER_LENGTH:var_buf;
    var_buf = O.data.len;
    while(var_buf > 0) O.data.buf[var_buf] = O.message[--var_buf];
    O.message.erase(0, O.data.len);
    return WSASend(connection, &O.data, 1, nullptr, 0, &O.overlapped, nullptr);
}
```

When the desktop client disconnects (it uses just closesocket() to do it, no shutdown()) the GetQueuedCompletionStatus returns TRUE and sets transfered to 0 - in this case WSAGetLastError() returns 64 (The specified network name is no longer available), and it has sense - client disconnected (line with `if(!QCS || (QCS && !transfered))`). But when the browser disconnects, the error codes confuse me... It can be 0, 997 (pending operation), 87 (invalid parameter)... and no codes related to end of connection.

Why do IOCP select this events? How can it select a pending operation? Why the error is 0 when 0 bytes transferred? Also it leads to endless trying to delete an object associated with the overlapped structure, because the destructor calls `~IO_Context(){ while(!HasOverlappedIoCompleted(&overlapped)) Sleep(1); }` for secure deleting. In `DeleteClient` call the socket is closing with `closesocket()`, but, as you can see, I'm posting a `shutdown(client->Socket(), SD_SEND);` call before it (in `FIN_CLOSE` section).

I understand that there are two sides of a connection and closing it on a server side does not mean that an other side will close it too. But I need to create a stabile server, immune to bad and half opened connections. For example, the user of web application can rapidly press F5 to reload page few times (yeah, some dudes do so :) ) - the connection will reopen few times, and the server must not lag or crash due to this actions.

How to handle this "bad" events in IOCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have many wrong code here.

```
while(WAIT_OBJECT_0 != WaitForSingleObject(EventShutdown, 0)){
    QCS = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(hIOCP, &transfered, (PULONG_PTR)&client, &overlapped, INFINITE);
```

this is not efficient and wrong code for stop `WorkerThread`. at first you do excess call `WaitForSingleObject`, use excess `EventShutdown` and main this anyway fail todo shutdown. if your code wait for packet inside `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` that you say `EventShutdown` - not break `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` call - you continue infinite wait here. correct way for shutdown - `PostQueuedCompletionStatus(hIOCP, 0, 0, 0)` instead call `SetEvent(EventShutdown)` and if worked thread view `client == 0` - he break loop. and usually you need have multiple `WorkerThread` (not single). and multiple calls `PostQueuedCompletionStatus(hIOCP, 0, 0, 0)` - exactly count of working threads. also you need synchronize this calls with io - do this only after all io already complete and no new io packets will be queued to iocp. so "null packets" must be the last queued to port

```
if(!QCS || (QCS && !transfered)){
            printf("Error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            DeleteClient(client);
            continue;
        }
```

if `!QCS` - the value in `client` not initialized, you simply can not use it and call `DeleteClient(client);` is wrong under this condition

when object (`client`) used from several thread - who must delete it ? what be if one thread delete object, when another still use it ? correct solution will be if you use reference counting on such object (client). and based on your code - you have single client per hIOCP ? because you retriever pointer for client as completion key for hIOCP which is single for all I/O operation on sockets bind to the hIOCP. all this is wrong design.

you need store pointer to client in `IO_Context`. and add reference to client in `IO_Context` and release client in `IO_Context` destructor.

```
class IO_Context : public OVERLAPPED {
    Client *client;
    ULONG opcode;
    // ...

public:
    IO_Context(Client *client, ULONG opcode) : client(client), opcode(opcode) {
        client->AddRef();
    }

    ~IO_Context() {
        client->Release();
    }

    void OnIoComplete(ULONG transfered) {
        OnIoComplete(RtlNtStatusToDosError(Internal), transfered);
    }

    void OnIoComplete(ULONG error, ULONG transfered) {
        client->OnIoComplete(opcode, error, transfered);
        delete this;
    }

    void CheckIoError(ULONG error) {
        switch(error) {
            case NOERROR:
            case ERROR_IO_PENDING:
                break;
            default:
                OnIoComplete(error, 0);
        }
    }
};
```

then are you have single `IO_Context` ? if yes, this is fatal error. the `IO_Context` must be unique for every I/O operation.

```
if (IO_Context* ctx = new IO_Context(client, op))
{
    ctx->CheckIoError(WSAxxx(ctx) == 0 ? NOERROR : WSAGetLastError());
}
```

and from worked thread**s**

```
ULONG WINAPI WorkerThread(void * param)
{
    ULONG_PTR key;
    OVERLAPPED *overlapped;
    ULONG transfered;
    while(GetQueuedCompletionStatus(hIOCP, &transfered, &key, &overlapped, INFINITE)) {
        switch (key){
        case '_io_':
            static_cast<IO_Context*>(overlapped)->OnIoComplete(transfered);
            continue;
        case 'stop':
            // ...
            return 0;
        default: __debugbreak();
        }
    }

    __debugbreak();
    return GetLastError();
}
```

the code like `while(!HasOverlappedIoCompleted(&overlapped)) Sleep(1);` is always wrong. absolute and always. never write such code.

`ctx = (IO_Context *)overlapped;` despite in your concrete case this give correct result, not nice and can be break if you change definition of `IO_Context`. you can use `CONTAINING_RECORD(overlapped, IO_Context, overlapped)` if you use `struct IO_Context{
    OVERLAPPED overlapped; }` but better use `class IO_Context : public OVERLAPPED` and `static_cast<IO_Context*>(overlapped)`

now about *Why do IOCP select this events? How to handle this "bad" events in IOCP?*

the IOCP *nothing select*. he simply signaling when I/O complete. all. which specific wsa errors you got on different network operation absolute independent from use IOCP or any other completion mechanism.

on graceful  disconnect is normal when error code is 0 and 0 bytes transferred in recv operation. you need permanent have recv request active after connection done, and if recv complete with 0 bytes transferred this mean that disconnect happens

Comment: Thans for your reply. The client object stores socket related info and client type, it has two IO_Context with fixed opcodes - for in and out. Can I reuse this contexts for related operations or I need to create new context for every operation as you told (IO context must be unique for EVERY I/O operation)?

Comment: @Iceman - must not be several I/O which use the same `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` (`OVERLAPPED`). you can reuse (why not ?) `IO_Context` after I/O in which it use finished. main it must be use only for single I/O at time. if not want every time allocate/free `IO_Context` context from heap, can have say lookaside and allocate/free to it.

Comment: Thanks! A lot of useful information for me! The msdn documentation on IOCP is “dry” and leaves many questions. I'll rewrite the server according to your comments.

Comment: @Iceman - iocp this is only way got notify about io complete, but it not related to concrete io type, and result of io not depend are you use io or say another completion way.

Comment: I just need to create new server which will work faster than current one with "thread-per-client" architecture. I tested the new IOCP server on a real host and the performance was great... but it crashes )) In general the server must accept appoximately 130 KBytes pes second from each streamer (~ 200 streamers a day), write a concrete stream to disk and retransmit it to watcher which requests it (200-1000 supervisors a day).

Comment: @Iceman - yes, iocp completions the best ways for server, can look for example (https://github.com/rbmm/LIB/blob/master/ASIO/socket.h, https://github.com/rbmm/LIB/blob/master/ASIO/port.h)

Comment: Sorry, I missed something... If to store client's ptr in IO context, so there is no reason to pass client's object as a completion key in `CreateIoCompletionPort` call when binding new connection, because I can get it from selected IO operation context. What do you suggest to pass there as a key? What key value do you expect in your example at line with `switch (key)`?

Comment: @Iceman - usually we have single *IOCP* (not need more) and many client's object - so we can not set pointer to client as completion key. if use system supplied IOCP via `BindIoCompletionCallback` it set pointer to user callback (*Function*) as  completion key. you can do this too for example. or if you use hardcoded pointer to function (all packets handled by single function) you can use here some tag (say `'_io_'`, `'stop'`, etc). can simply pass 0 and not use

Comment: Ok, thank you again! ) And the last thing I would like to ask: The IOCP will notify only if i'll init send or recv operation or even if i'll not  take any action but the other side of connection will perform some action on this connection?

Comment: you got notify in IOCP exactly when your io operation complete. any but **your** (send,recv, connect, disconnect)